# prevent parent page from loading inside jquery dialog box on button click

Tags: jquery

I have a jquery dialog box that loads a php file (shopping_cart_temp.php) via ajax. The php file has 3 ajax buttons, remove, add 1, or minus 1. The href for all 3 buttons is #. The problem is, when I click on any of the 3 ajax buttons, the parent page loads inside the jquery dialog box instead of completing the ajax button action. After doing some research I found that it could be because event.preventDefault or onclick=return false; are not present or not working. I can see this question or similar questions has been asked many times, but each solution I tried didn't work for me. Can you help me solve this please?

```
 $info_box_contents[$cur_row][] = array('align' => 'center',
                                         'params' => 'class="productListing-data" valign="middle"',
                                         'text' => tep_draw_checkbox_field('cart_delete[]', $products[$i]['id']) .
                                         '<a class="cart-remove" style="visibility:hidden;" href="#" rel="' . $products[$i]['id'] . '">'
                                         . tep_image(DIR_WS_ICONS . 'cancel.png', TABLE_HEADING_REMOVE) . '</a>' .
                                         '<span style="display:none;" id="pn-' . $products[$i]['id'] . '">' .
                                         '<a href="' . tep_href_link(FILENAME_PRODUCT_INFO, 'products_id=' . $products[$i]['id']) . '">' . $products[$i]['name'] . '</a></span>')  ;
```

Answer (score 0):

it's your `window.location` in the buttons that's causing the issue.

When you set `window.location =` it's loading the URL of the parent page (because the dynamic content is not a child page).

To run those functions, I believe you will need to look at jQuery .load - 
http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: I have tried adding href="Javascript: void(0);" to the button code but it made no difference, the parent window still opened inside the dialog box.

Comment: sorry may be I didnt make that very clear, yeah I have tried  href="Javascript: void(0); and onclick=return false; as well, may be I am adding the code to the wrong place I dont know I am a newbie to these dialog boxes. The script above loads php file (shopping_cart_temp.php) via ajax (about half way down the code. Its the ajax buttons in the shopping_cart_temp.php that are the problem, when I click on them, instead of updating the cart and keeping shopping_cart_temp.php loaded in the dialog, the parent page loads inside the dialog instead.

Comment: the window.location = buttons are in the dialog script, its the ajax buttons in the shopping_cart_temp.php that are the problem, would it help if i posted that script instead, or am I missing something in your answer?

Comment: @mcreedy - please, that would be great if you could post your code.

Comment: see updated code please, it is the button starting a class="cart-remove"

Comment: @mcreedy - I'd need to see both bits of code - if it's too long to post here, just put it into a pastebin.